# grepl across multiple, specified columns

Tags: r, grepl

I want to create a new column in my data frame that is either TRUE or FALSE depending on whether a term occurs in two specified columns. 
This is some example data:

```
AB <- c('CHINAS PARTY CONGRESS','JAPAN-US RELATIONS','JAPAN TRIES TO')
TI <- c('AMERICAN FOREIGN POLICY', 'CHINESE ATTEMPTS TO', 'BRITAIN HAS TEA')
AU <- c('AUTHOR 1', 'AUTHOR 2','AUTHOR 3')
M  <- data.frame(AB,TI,AU)
```

I can do it for one column, or the other, but I cannot figure out how to do it for both. In other words, I don't know how to combine these two lines that would not mutually overwrite each other.

```
M$China <- mapply(grepl, "CHINA|CHINESE|SINO", x=M$AB)
M$China <- mapply(grepl, "CHINA|CHINESE|SINO", x=M$TI)
```

It is important that I specify the columns, I cannot choose the whole data.frame.I have looked for other similar questions, but none seemed to apply to my case and I haven't been able to adapt any existing examples. This is what would make sense to me:

```
M$China <- mapply(grepl, "CHINA|CHINESE|SINO", x=(M$AB|M$TI)
```

Comment: Try `Map(grepl, "CHINA|CHINESE|SINO", M)`

Comment: I am not exactly sure what Map does, but it gives this output 
$`CHINA|CHINESE|SINO`
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE

$<NA>
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE

$<NA>
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE. It seems to run over the whole dataframe, also it does not add the new column.

Comment: It is in a `list` format.  You can convert it to data.frame by wrapping `data.frame` or assign it to the columns `M[] <- Map(grepl, "CHINA|CHINESE|SINO", M)`

Comment: In that case it overwrites the values, which shouldn't happen.

Comment: It is not clear about your expected output

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using:

```
M$China <- !!rowSums(sapply(M[1:2], grepl, pattern = "CHINA|CHINESE|SINO"))
```

gives:

> ```
> > M
>                      AB                      TI       AU China
> 1 CHINAS PARTY CONGRESS AMERICAN FOREIGN POLICY AUTHOR 1  TRUE
> 2    JAPAN-US RELATIONS     CHINESE ATTEMPTS TO AUTHOR 2  TRUE
> 3        JAPAN TRIES TO         BRITAIN HAS TEA AUTHOR 3 FALSE
> ```

What this does:

- `sapply(M[1:2], grepl, pattern = "CHINA|CHINESE|SINO")` loops over the two `AB` and `TI` columns and looks whether one of the parts of the pattern (`"CHINA|CHINESE|SINO"`) is present.
- The `sapply`-call returns a matrix of `TRUE`/`FALSE` values:

  ```
          AB    TI
  [1,]  TRUE FALSE
  [2,] FALSE  TRUE
  [3,] FALSE FALSE
  ```
- With `rowSums` you check how many `TRUE`-values each row has.
- By adding `!!` in front of`rowSums` you convert all values from the `rowSums`-call higher than zero to `TRUE` and all eros to `FALSE`.

Comment: YES, that works! Don't completely understand it, but I guess in M[1:2] I can specify any column number I want, also in my own data.frame, no?

Comment: @SCW `1:2` specifies indeed the column positions

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @SCW added now an explanation as well

Answer (score 3):

If we need to collapse to a single vector, use the `Map` to loop through the columns, apply the `pattern` to get a `list` of `logical` vector, then `Reduce` it to a `logical` vector using `|`

```
M$China <- Reduce(`|`, Map(grepl, "CHINA|CHINESE|SINO", M))
M
#                     AB                      TI       AU China
#1 CHINAS PARTY CONGRESS AMERICAN FOREIGN POLICY AUTHOR 1  TRUE
#2    JAPAN-US RELATIONS     CHINESE ATTEMPTS TO AUTHOR 2  TRUE
#3        JAPAN TRIES TO         BRITAIN HAS TEA AUTHOR 3 FALSE
```

---

Or using the same methodology in `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
M %>%
   mutate_all(funs(str_detect(., "CHINA|CHINESE|SINO")))  %>% 
   reduce(`|`) %>%
   mutate(M, China = .)
```